# How to compare char* with string in boost unit test?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, loops, testing, boost

I have got code like below:

```
BOOST_FIXTURE_TEST_CASE(test, TestSuite1)
{
    unsigned int length = 5;
    char* content1=new char[length];
    content1="abcde";
    string content2("abcde");

    BOOST_REQUIRE( length == content2.length() );

    for(unsigned int i=0;i<5;++i)
    {
        BOOST_CHECK( content1[i] == content2[i] );
    }

    if(content1 != nullptr)
    {
        delete[] content1;
        content1 = nullptr;
    }
}
```

The question is how to compare char* with string in boost unit test?
I have used loop, but I don't know if it is a good way.
Is there any better solution? Thank you very much.

Comment: `char* content1=new char[length]; content1="abcde";` Start with fixing that. And the fixed loop length. Then see `strcpy` and `strcmp`, and `.c_str()`

Comment: I wonder what you consider to be the value of such "unit tests". You don't need to test if standard-library classes work.

Answer (score 2):

Use `BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL` so that you get decent output in event of a failure. Using your code (after fixing the missing strcpy):

```
BOOST_FIXTURE_TEST_CASE(test, TestSuite1)
{
    // Set up for testing. I assume that in production, `content1` will
    // come from the code under test.
    char* content1=new char[6];
    strcpy(content1, "abcde");

    const std::string reference("abcde");
    BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(reference, content1);

    delete[] content1;
}
```

This passes if `content1` matches the string reference. If there is a failure:

```
Running 1 test cases...
test_demo.cpp:13: error: in "TestSuite1/test": check reference == content1 has failed [abcde != abcd2e]

*** 1 failure is detected in the test module "Test_demo"
```

Answer (score 1):

Compare using `strcmp`:

```
std::string s = "anything";
char* c = "anything";
BOOST_CHECK(strcmp(s.c_str(),c)==0);
```

Comment: It's good solution, but I want to compare it in boost unit test.

Comment: I don't know because I have almost no experience with boost, but won't `BOOST_CHECK( strcmp(s.c_str(),c)==0 );` work?

Answer (score 0):

Your code design is flawed as you create an array of fixed length and do not terminate it with a null terminated character even though you intend to compare it with a string.

What you could do is use c.str strin member function to return the string under a C character style and then use strcmp function (win APi).
But you do need to make sure your C array is null terminated before intending to compare it with converted string variable.

Answer (score 0):

Why not using the std::string::compare method :

```
BOOST_CHECK(content2.compare(0, length, content1)==0)
```

Answer (score 0):

It has nothing to do with boost, you compare an `std::string` and a `char *` the same as you would in any other situation:

```
content2.compare(content1) == 0
content2 == content1
```

If you're writing C++ and using `std::string` then you should stick to C++ and not use C functions like `strcmp`.

You also have other problems in your code. For example this piece:

```
char* content1=new char[length];
content1="abcde";
```

doesn't do exactly what you think. You first allocate an array of `char`s then you immediately set the `content1` pointer to point to something else. This doesn't copy `abcde` into the space you allocated, it changes the actual pointer to another address in memory. The space you allocated previously for `content1` is forever lost.

Then later you have this:

```
if(content1 != nullptr)
{
    delete[] content1;
    content1 = nullptr;
}
```

Again, this doesn't do what you might think. It doesn't free the space you allocated at the beginning of your program with `new` because `content1` doesn't point to that space anymore. It points to some memory where the `abcde` string is stored, but you haven't allocated that space so you shouldn't try to free it. Doing this leads to undefined behavior and your program may crash or do other weird stuff.

You should learn to pay attention to what the compiler tells you during compilation. This line:

```
content1="abcde";
```

for sure generates a warning, read it carefully and try to understand what it's telling you.

Answer (score 0):

Actually just using `BOOST_TEST`

[BOOST_TEST](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/test/doc/html/boost_test/testing_tools/extended_comparison/strings.html) compares them without extra steps.

```
BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE( test_strings )
{
  const char* a = "test1";
  const char* b = "test2";
  const char* c = "test1";
  BOOST_TEST(a == b);
  BOOST_TEST(a == c);
}
```

NOTE: User @Logman points out important issues in the comments below.

Comment: This is clearly wrong, you do not compare std::string and cstring here, but two pointers to the cstrings (const char*).

Comment: The problem here is that `a == c` may evaluate to true but if `a` or `c` would be a runtime generated cstring then this would fail even if the text would be the same.